# Move OS from one hard disk to another one

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot

My notebook, running a dual boot system of Windows 7 and OpenSuse just got a new secondary internal hard disk (NVMe SSD). Now I would like to move one of those OS (preferably OpenSuse) to this hard disk, in order to be able to increase the size of the Windows partition. Still I would like to boot both OS, i.e. leave the boot loader intact. The main boot loader is the OpenSuse-boot loader, which then can (if selected) load the Windows boot loader.

My new hard disk has a size of ~500 GByte, while the old linux partitions occupy ~250 GByte. 
Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: Moving a Linux install to another disk is far simplier than moving a windows install so that's good - have you actually tried following the numerous guides online to do so? Also, **MAKE BACKUPS FIRST**!.

Comment: Linux is behind the Windows partition, thus I assume that it is easier to move and to expand the Windows partition afterwards.

Comment: One way would be booting a "Clonezilla" live image, cloning the partitions of your linux installation to the new disk, expanding them, booting your "old" linux installation, using `grub-install` or `grub2-install` depending on grub's version (assuming that you use grub) to make sure that grub is installed properly on your new partition and maybe to write the bootloader to the new disk's Master Boot Record and using `grub-mkconfig` or `grub2-mkconfig` to update grubs configuration file called "grub.cfg" located on the new boot partition.

Comment: Then you should test your linux installation on your new disk and if it works, you can boot windows, open the `diskmgmt.msc` program, delete the old linux partitions and finally resize the windows partitions.